# CMS Image Padding - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages, media-images

Have added two images to same line, they auto fill the width - but how can I remove the padding between the images?

And remove the "line break" so I can have e.g. 4 images (2x2) without any padding in between??

The code is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/1.jpg"}}" style="width:100%"/>
</div><div class="col-md-6">
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/2.jpg"}}" style="width:100%"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Confirm padding is given to div or image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using bootstrap. you need to add **.no-gutters** with **col-md-6** then both images are in same line without padding.

Otherwise you can you your custom css for padding.

```
.custom-class > [class*=col-]{
   padding-right:0;
   padding-left:0;
}
```

**Do not use inline style in div tag.**

for line break add this style

```
img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```